# Google Chrome; Textarea max characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

So I'm working on a Phonegap app and having some trouble with the textarea and maxlength.

When the Phonegap app is built on Google Chrome, it is possible to write more than 255 characters with the use of line break/enter on the phone itself.

Heres my html:

```
<textarea class="content" wrap="physical" rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="255"></textarea>
```

And heres my JS/jQuery:

```
$('.content').keyup( function(e){

    /*var char = 255 - $(this).val().length;
    if(char < 0) char = 0;
    $('.char_left').text(char);*/

    var y = 255;
    var x = $(this).val();
    x = x.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"");
    x = x.length;
    if (x >= y) {
        $('.char_left').text('Limit!');
    } else {
        var ch = y - x;
        $('.char_left').text(ch);
    }

});
```

I have commented out a earlier version I used, and that worked in the default android browser.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
  MaxLength = 255;

  $('.content').keyup(function(e)
  {
       if ($(this).val().length > MaxLength)
       {
           $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, MaxLength));
      }
  });
```

It will ensure that no matter what, it will not go over 255. It basically chops off anything after MaxLength.

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to work on this. But will you the concept and make it fit :) Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this : check if length of value of `textarea` is greater than `maxlength` specified then return false, otherwise don't do anything.

```
$(function(){
    var maxlength = $('.content').attr('maxlength');
    $('.content').keyup(function(){
       if($(this).val().length > maxlength)
           return false;
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/1g63gjLx/)**

Comment: Hey, just tried it out. But still doesn't work in Google Chrome on my phone. I think it has todo something with line break/enter. Because when I post it to my database, it removes some part that I can type in Google Chrome mobile.

Comment: I tried this with chrome browser on my desktop, I don't know if mobile browser has any other configuration or setting that does not allow this function to work properly.

Comment: But I will work out from your code, thanks again! :)